# How can I get the safeAreaLayout info for my GameScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

Am trying to develop a game and am not using storyboard at all. Am building it all via code.
I know how to get the safeAreaLayout info, thanks to this forum) for a UIViewController. My thought was I'd be able to attach my GameScene: SKScene to that and go from there. Found out the hard way that's not the case. I have searched so hard and have tried all the example I found find for the likes of

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

and

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

And every method I've tried returns either sets of **0's**, or the full height of the screen **812**

I would like to think that there is a proper method for getting the proper safeArea info to the initial GameScene of my app. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

You get the 812 pixels height because that's the scene height. In `SpriteKit` the games are full screen, you don't need to worry about the safe areas.

From `GameViewController` present the scene you want to display, in my case `MainScene`.

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView?
{
    // create a new scene of type Main Scene
        
    let scene = MainScene()

     // set the new (MainScene) settings
        
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        
    // present the scene
        
    view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

If you want to know the size of the scene in MainScene, just get the values like this.

```
class MainScene: SKScene
{
    override func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        let screenHeight = self.scene!.size.height
        let screenWidth = self.scene!.size.width
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and I still got the full screen height return in GameViewController, and for some reason full height, but  no width return in the GameScene code.

As for not having to worry about safe areas in SpriteKit, doing nothing...and my GameScene takes up full screen with controls I make being in safe areas. There must be a way.